# os.chdir can't find remote shared driver

Tags: python-2.7, remote-access

very simple task:

srcdir="Q://Waveforms//Cispr16-1-2//Pk"

os.chdir(srcdir)

the interpreter says:

WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Q://Waveforms//Cispr16-1-2//Pk'

from cmd prompt the remote driver is visible:

Volume in drive Q is USERDATA
Volume Serial Number is CB9A-E149

Directory of Q:\Waveforms\Cispr16-1-2\Pk

13/02/2019  12:21              .
13/02/2019  12:21              ..
13/02/2019  12:21             8.225 F1--Pk--00000.trc
               1 File(s)          8.225 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  84.622.512.128 bytes free

Most likely this is a windows10 security issue, not letting Python access the sahred folder. Has anyone experienced the same issue and has found a solution?

thanks
Mastro59

Answer (score 1):

The double `//` should be a single `/`. Or `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with / and // and \ and \ none of these worked with windows10, but
in windows7 this command works:

os.chdir("Q://Waveforms")

for others having the same problem here is the solution for Windows10.

it is required to access the share using the ip address and share name.

the shared drive was named "d"

in python this syntax works:

os.chdir("\\ipaddress\sharename\folder") [ 4 \ AND 2 \]
OR 
os.chdir("//ipaddress/sharename/folder")

this worked well:

os.chdir("\\192.168.147.143\d\Waveforms")  [note:IN TEXT MESSAGE I AM TYPING 4\  AND 2\ BUT THE POST ONLY SHOWS 2\ AND 1]

OR

os.chdir("//192.168.147.143/d/Waveforms")

result:

Current Working Directory  D:\products\MyscopeControl\src

Directory changed to: \192.168.147.143\d\Waveforms